# How to show more decimal digits on an axis?

Tags: r, plot

The code

```
a <- 10^-7
f <- function(x) 1+a*cos(x)
plot(f, 0, 2*pi)
```

produces

[image]

but smaller values of `a` (e.g. `10^-8`) produce the following:

[image]

How can I make the y-axis in the latter case show the decimal places as in the first plot? (I do not use ggplot2.)

Comment: what are those "smaller values"? I am unable to replicate

Comment: Given your example, what would you expect those y-axis marks to look like? `axTicks(2)` gives me `[1] 0.9999999 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000001 1.0000001`, not exactly awesome graph-worthy axis ticks.

Comment: @PKumar  I get the second plot using `a=10^-8`.

Comment: @r2evans I want the plot with `a=10^-8` to look similar to the one with `a=10^-7` (i.e., `0.99999999`,...,`1.00000001`); `axTicks(2)` gives me `[1] 1 1 1 1 1` .

Comment: Might I suggest instead that you also limit the number of axis ticks to be accurate and unique values? For instance, as in my comment, `pretty` comes up with a couple identical values, something you need to be vigilant to prevent ... otherwise, which one is right?

Comment: `pretty` seems to be working pretty well till the numeric precision hits, you just have to format it with large enough number of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `formatC` and `pretty`:

```
a <- 1e-10                             
plot(f, 0, 2*pi, yaxt="n")  # no default y axis
p <- pretty(par("usr")[3:4])  # find nice breaks at actual y range
l <- formatC(p, format="f", digits=12) # format w/12 digits
axis(2, at=p, labels=l)
```

[image: labels w/12 digits]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer you are needing to add more decimals to your plot

```
value = function(p){c(min(p$y),
                  mean(c(median(p$y),min(p$y))),
                  median(p$y),
                  mean(c(median(p$y),max(p$y))),
                  max(p$y))}

par(mar = c(5,5,4,2), mfrow = c(1,2))
options(digits=15, scipen = 999)
a <- 10^-7
f <- function(x) as.double(1+a*cos(x))

p1 = plot(f, 0, 2*pi, cex.axis = 0.7, las = 1, ylab = "", yaxt = "n", main = "a=10^-7")
axis(2, at = value(p1),labels = sprintf("%.8f", value(p1)), cex.axis = .7, las = 1)

a <- 10^-8
p2=plot(f, 0, 2*pi, cex.axis = 0.7, las = 1, ylab = "", yaxt = "n", main = "a=10^-8")
axis(2, at = value(p2),labels = sprintf("%.8f", value(p2)), cex.axis = .7, las = 1)
```

[image]